# delete QSyntaxHighLighter from QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to remove QSyntaxHighLighter that was set on QTextEdit, I try:

```
 hig = self.textEdit.findChildren(QSyntaxHighlighter)
 del hig
```

but it does'nt work

It was set with:

```
highlight = syntax.PythonHighlighter(self.textEdit, (self.le.text()))
```

I'm using this highlightning to mark searched words, but in next search previous result remain highlighted

any ideas?

@Edit

```
class PythonHighlighter (QSyntaxHighlighter):
keywords = []
def __init__(self, document, pattern):
    QSyntaxHighlighter.__init__(self, document)

    self.keywords.append(pattern)

    rules = []

    rules += [(r'%s' % w, 0, STYLES['keyword'])
        for w in PythonHighlighter.keywords]

    self.rules = [(QRegExp(pat), index, fmt)
        for (pat, index, fmt) in rules]



def highlightBlock(self, text):
    """Apply syntax highlighting to the given block of text.
    """
    # Do other syntax formatting
    for expression, nth, format in self.rules:
        index = expression.indexIn(text, 0)

        while index >= 0:
            # We actually want the index of the nth match
            index = expression.pos(nth)
            length = expression.cap(nth).length()
            self.setFormat(index, length, format)
            index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length)
    self.keywords = []
    self.setCurrentBlockState(0)
```

Comment: `del` does *not* delete an object, but only a reference to an object. In particular the sequence `a = get_an_object(); del a` is guaranteed to be a no-op if `get_an_object()` returns a reference to an object that has an other reference(like in your case). AFAIK you cannot set a syntax highlighter that only highlights part of the text. I believe you should show more code and provide a bit mor e explanation on you want to do/are doing.

Comment: I'm highlightning only word that has been found in text, so I can mark one words, but in the next search loop I want to previous highlights be unhighlight.

Comment: You can use `highlight.setDocument(None)` to disconnect the highlighter and the textedit.

Comment: It solves problem partially, I can remove highlight but word highlighted in previous search appear again marked.